# "result":null in php, as I am trying to pass on value to JS as a number from php

Tags: php, null

On my first line I am trying to get my 'eventid' from my 'newevent' table in the database. After which, I am trying to get other values 'numofticket' and 'numofticketleft' from the same table with 'eventid' as the primary key and converting it to a number value so that I am able to perform a calculation in my javascript.

PHP:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, 
OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

error_reporting(E_ERROR);

include("global.php");


$conn = new mysqli(server, dbuser, dbpw, db);


$query1 = "select eventid from newevent";
$result1 = $conn->query($query1);





$result = $conn->query("select numofticket, numofticketleft from newevent 
where eventid = '$eventid'");
$getvalue = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);



$json_out = "[" . json_encode(array("result"=>$getvalue)) . "]";

echo $json_out;

$conn->close();

?>
```

JS:

```
function progress() {

var url = serverURL() + "/file.php";


            // Call Ajax
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'GET',

                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (arr) {


                    var result = arr[0].result;
                    var numofticket = arr[0].numofticket;
                    var numofticketleft=arr[0].numofticketleft;
                    var eventid = arr[0].eventid;
                    var going = numofticket - numofticketleft;

                    $('#going').append(going + " " + "is going 
                    for this event");
                    $('#bar').append("<div id='barbox_a'> 
                     </div>" +
                        "<div class='bar blank'></div>" + "<div class='bar' style='width: ",
                        going * 1.5, " px'>" + "</div>\n");

                },

                error: function () {

                }

            });





 }

progress();
```

Comment: And that variable $eventid you are using in the second query, got its value assigned where exactly …?

Comment: what i am trying to do is basically get the 'numofticket' and 'numofticketleft' values from my database by using 'eventid' as my primary key identifier and converting these values into number so that i am able to perform my calculation in the javascript

Comment: i am rather new to php and not sure where it went wrong

Comment: It went wrong in the place where you are using the variable $eventid, because you did not assign a value to that anywhere before …

Comment: Do you want this for a single event id, or for all that are in the newevent table? If the latter, you’d need to use a loop over the result of the first query to begin with. And if the former, then you still need to at least _read_ the id from the first record that query returned.

Comment: i need this for all that are in the newevent table, which is also why I used the eventid = '$eventid' function, as different events will have different 'numofticket' and 'numofticketleft'

Comment: _“which is also why I used the eventid = '$eventid' function”_ - A.G.A.I.N., `$eventid` does not have any value, because you didn’t assign one _anywhere_ …

Comment: Welcome to the past.  Question is 3 months old